# Oracle Database Object SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle Database. There are two object tables `SHOPS(S_NUM, S_NAME, TEL)`. And `PRODUCTS(P_NUM, P_NAME, P_VAL, P_PRICE, SHOP_NUM)`. How to write in Oracle Object SQL language query to get how much there are PRODUCTS in the shop with name "SHOP1"?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_SHOP as Object (
   S_NUM Integer,
   S_NAME Varchar(30),
   TEL Varchar2(300)  
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_PRODUCT as Object (
   P_NUM Integer,
   P_VAL Integer,
   P_PRICE Number,
   SHOP_NUM INteger,
   P_NAME Varchar(30),
   TEL Varchar2(300)  
);

CREATE TABLE SHOPS of T_SHOP;
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS of T_PRODUCT;

Shops:
    +---------------------------------------------------------------+
    |            S_NUM S_NAME                         TEL           |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------+
    |          0 Shop1                          +371256215215       |
    |          1 Shop2                          +37125623232323232  |
    |          2 Shop3                          +37125623223323     |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------+
Products:
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |          P_NUM      P_VAL    P_PRICE   SHOP_NUM P_NAME                         TEL      |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |          0          1         10          1 SIRI                           332323233232 |
    |          1          1         11          1 SIRI2                          332323233232 |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
select count(distinct P.P_NUM) 
from SHOPS S
left join PRODUCTS p on P.SHOP_NUM = S.S_NUM 
Where S.S_NAME = 'SHOP1'
group by P.SHOP_NUM
```

Small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abaa04583a9279b8e338502c4ceaf752)

Comment: It's right. But it is not an OBJECT oracle style. Please see the updated code in my question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that, my fault. Then I agree with what @a_horse_with_no_name wrote in the comment. Cheers!

Comment: @Kantakt And what was wrong with my query ? Your answer is the same as mine and you did not voted for him and did not mark it as correct ? You said that it is not in "OBJECT oracle style" ?

Comment: I just understand what Object and Regular SQL are the same after I got the second answer from Akr0n. I was thinking that for Object must be something special. Thanks!

Comment: @Kantakt . . . I don't think this should be the accepted answer.  (1) `LEFT JOIN` is not needed.  (2) The tables are in the wrong order.  (3) I doubt `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is required (it isn't based on the information in the question).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do not appreciate the way it is commented but I do appreciate the comments in hand. I have therefore changed the "(2) The tables are in the wrong order."

Comment: @Voka . . . The comment was directed at the OP and directly related to the quality of the answer.  I don't downvote as a rule, but I do convey my opinions about questions and answers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes I see that it is for the OP. But you have not seen what happened here and you can maybe see it from the comments and answers... And I still think that the general opinion is better than the one like your comment here. General opinion = without this : "@Kantakt . . . I don't think this should be the accepted answer."

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what I need is:

```
 SELECT count(p.p_num) FROM 
 SHOPS H 
 JOIN PRODUCTS P ON H.S_NUM = P.SHOP_NUM
 WHERE S_NAME = 'Shop2'
 group by P.SHOP_NUM;

+----------------+
| COUNT(P.P_NUM) |
+----------------+
| -------------- |
|              2 |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `S_NUM` and `SHOP_NUM` are both referring to the same values you can use `JOIN` to get a view filtered by `S_NAME`. Something like:

```
SELECT
    H.S_NUM
    , H.S_NAME
    , H.TEL
    , P.P_NAME
    , P.P_PRICE
FROM SHOPS H
JOIN PRODUCTS P ON H.S_NUM = P.SHOP_NUM
WHERE S_NAME = 'SHOP1'
```

Comment: Thanks! Really what I need is SELECT
    count(p.p_num)
FROM SHOPS H
JOIN PRODUCTS P ON H.S_NUM = P.SHOP_NUM
WHERE S_NAME = 'Shop2'
group by P.SHOP_NUM; This request I made according to your answer.